# Where is Jondum Bau?

Tags: mass-effect-3

A couple missions into the game I got an email from Jondum Bau saying he'd like to meet me at the Citadel Embassies. I'm there and according to the map, I should be standing right on top of him, but he's nowhere to be found.

Where is he and how do I talk to him?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He should be on the Citadel Embassies level right outside the C-Sec office. I'm not sure if it matters, but I received the email and talked to him right after completing the mission on Palaven.

[image]
[image]

Since, given the title, other people might stumble across this question when they're looking for him again later in that quest, he'll be not far from the "5" on that same map above.

Comment: I think the timing does matter, i went looking for him awhile after i got the email (2-3 missions) and hes not there